# How would you say "please give me 10 of this"?

Tags: counters, numbers

for example, これを一つください is please give me 10 of this.
then how should I say if it were 10, 11, 12, and more...?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can stay with the form:

> これを〇〇ください

But beyond 9, you'd need to switch from the traditional *hitotsu-futatsu* numerals to *ichi-ni*-style and add an appropriate counter for the item.

For a generic counter you would use:

- 個{こ} - so for "10 of this": 10個 
  (じゅっこ) then 11個 (じゅういっこ), 12個 (じゅうにこ), etc.

But depending on the requested object itself, you might use:

- 本{ほん} for long, thin objects (like pens or kushi-katsu): 10本 (じゅっぽん), 11本 (じゅういっぽん), 12本 (じゅうにほん), ...
- 冊{さつ} for books/brochures:  10冊 (じゅっさつ), 11冊 (じゅういっさつ), 12冊 (じゅうにさつ), ...
- or other counters [listed here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Japanese_counter_word#Extended_list_of_counters)

Notice that many of these compounds have irregular pronunciation.

And also you can use them for the quantities below 10: 3個 (さんこ), 4本 (よんほん), 5枚 (ごまい)

Comment: You don't *need* to switch for 10.  You can still use 「とお」.

Comment: Ok, I will try :)